# Why Tomcat logs everything of my app in its console?

Tags: spring, tomcat, logging, log4j2

I just migrate my app to log4j2, this is my config, and it is loaded progammatically from the contextInitialized() method of my app:

```
status = error
dest = err
name = myappConfig

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n

appender.standard.type = RollingFile
appender.standard.name = Standard
appender.standard.fileName = ${myapphome}/log/server/${cod}/myapp.log
appender.standard.filePattern = ${myapphome}/log/server/${cod}/myapp.%i.log
appender.standard.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.standard.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.standard.policies.type = Policies
appender.standard.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.standard.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.standard.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.standard.strategy.max = 5

#-----------------------------------
logger.myapp.name = com.myapp
logger.myapp.level = info
logger.myapp.additivity = false
logger.myapp.appenderRef.standard.ref = Standard
#-----------------------------------

rootLogger.level = warn
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

I get a full trace in the tomcat console, why? For example in the console I get all info of spring framework logs. However file logs are correct.

Comment: Am I reading this right? You have set your root logger to the console? It seems like you should expect everything to go to stdout, then...

Comment: Yes, but at warn level...